# How to disable CORS in Spring Security within Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I want to completely remove CORS from Spring Boot (2.3.3.RELEASE) with Spring Security.

There is `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure` method for `HttpSecurity` object where I can call `cors().disable()` but it seems not to work.

```
class MySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().disable();
    }
}
```

With just above snippet I still get CORS errors while accessing endpoints from my frontend application.

Instead of that I have to override `addCorsMappings` from `WebMvcConfigurer` interface like below .

Why is that? Why it is not enough to call `http.cors().disable()`?

```
class MySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedOrigins("*");
    }
```

Comment: You can't enable CORS without a configuration. `http.cors().disable()` means that the server is not supporting Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.

Comment: @dur what does it mean it doesn't support? Should it not stop validating CORS related headers then? Thanks for explaining 

Comment: I edited my comment, it was confusing. Your problem is just a wording problem. By default no CORS is allowed, that means no sharing. You have to enable CORS with a configuration.

Comment: I get it, thank you @dur 

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to create a global cors configuration in your spring boot project.Create a class and annotate it with @Configuration. You can follow this example below.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

 @Bean
 public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
     return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
             registry.addMapping("/api/**")
               .allowedOrigins("http://domain2.com")
               .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE")
               .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
               .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
               .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
       }
    };
  }
}
```

Here is the full guide that spring framework provides https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

Comment: Thanks Isa, I already put similar example in the question :)